# PL/SQL Mutating Trigger - alternative ideas?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

The code below is meant to trigger when a new record is inserted and is meant to change the new record's field but I get a mutating error when trying to insert. What can I do to fix this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_auto_rating_desc
AFTER INSERT ON reviews
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    vn_rating NUMBER(1);
    vc_rating_description reviews.rating_description%TYPE := '';

BEGIN
    vn_rating := :NEW.overall_rating;
    CASE vn_rating
        WHEN 1 THEN vc_rating_description := 'VERY POOR';
        WHEN 2 THEN vc_rating_description := 'POOR';
        WHEN 3 THEN vc_rating_description :='OKAY';
        WHEN 4 THEN vc_rating_description := 'GOOD';
        WHEN 5 THEN vc_rating_description := 'VERY GOOD';
        ELSE dbms_output.put_line('NO SUCH REVIEW');
    END CASE;

    dbms_output.put_line(vn_rating || ' = ' || vc_rating_description);
    UPDATE reviews SET rating_description = vc_rating_description WHERE review_id = :NEW.review_id;

END trig_auto_rating_desc;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do an update within the trigger if you are modifying the values on a row by row basis.
Just run your case then

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_auto_rating_desc
BEFORE INSERT
ON REVIEWS
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    vn_rating NUMBER(1);
    vc_rating_description reviews.rating_description%TYPE := '';

BEGIN
    vn_rating := :NEW.overall_rating;
    CASE vn_rating
        WHEN 1 THEN vc_rating_description := 'VERY POOR';
        WHEN 2 THEN vc_rating_description := 'POOR';
        WHEN 3 THEN vc_rating_description :='OKAY';
        WHEN 4 THEN vc_rating_description := 'GOOD';
        WHEN 5 THEN vc_rating_description := 'VERY GOOD';
        ELSE vc_rating_description := 'Invalid value';
        --you will never see dbms_output from a trigger
        --ELSE dbms_output.put_line('NO SUCH REVIEW');
    END CASE;
    :new.rating_description := vc_rating_description;

END trig_auto_rating_desc;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'm getting an error on the line :new.rating_description = vc_rating_description, is that meant to be ":="?

Comment: I still get an error saying it "cannot change NEW values for this trigger type" erroring at line 1

Comment: @theglobin That's because you're using an `AFTER` trigger. Switch it over to a `BEFORE` trigger and it should work. Alternatively, you could do the case statement in the insert statement itself.

Comment: @Boneist Thank you! That was the solution, everything works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

A mutating table occurs when a statement causes a trigger to fire and that trigger references the table that caused the trigger. The best way to avoid such problems is to not use triggers or you may try below:

- Changed the trigger to an after trigger.
- Changed it from a row level trigger to a statement level trigger.
- Convert to a Compound Trigger.
- Made the trigger autonomous with a commit in it.

Comment: I've already got it as an after trigger so I don't understand why I'm getting this error, it updates the row AFTER it has been inserted, unless it isn't actually inserted until after the trigger has finished?

Comment: You may try for autonomous transaction

Comment: autonomous transaction is not the solution here (and, on the whole, for any trigger). @theglobin >  You need to read up on triggers. I suggest looking at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm), where you can see `An AFTER trigger cannot change NEW field values, because the triggering statement runs before the trigger fires.`. In other words, you can change the values being inserted *before* the row is inserted, but once it's been inserted, that's it. As I said above, use a `BEFORE` trigger or do the change as part of the insert statement.

Comment: @Boneist Thanks again for that suggestion, it works beautifully